# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position) getting error "position is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

In my application need to get current location, I have tried with below code, I am getting error like position is not defined. The error am getting the API object 'Position' itself is not defined.

```
try {
    if (event.handled !== true) {
        event.handled = true;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var geoOptions = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 };
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { // geoSuccess
                $("#clientPersonalDetailesDiv #longitude").val(position.coords.longitude);
                $("#clientPersonalDetailesDiv #latitude").val(position.coords.latitude);
                $.hcmobile.hideLoader();
            }, function (error) { // geoError
                $.hcmobile.hideLoader();
                if (error.code == '3') {
                    $.hcmobile.alertBox("ErrorMessage", "GPS is not available on this device");
                }
                else {
                    $.hcmobile.alertBox("ErrorMessage", error.message + 'You must turn on location services to use this feature');
                    //$.hcmobile.alertBox("ErrorMessage", "You must turn on location services to use this feature");
                }
            }, geoOptions);
        }
    }
}
catch (e)
{
}
```

I am getting error code 1, it says :

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

I have attached screen shot for more information.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The error am getting the API object 'Position' itself is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this feature only works on secure connections (served over https) as your error already says. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) for reference.